# compiler use more ram to read data from file than expected

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, erlang, kernel

While working with the `chardev` in the Linux kernel, I observed something interesting. The function `my_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)` is used to read data from the Linux module. After opening the file system and reading it, I printed the value of `count` and noticed it was equal to `12288`. However, in my code, I specified to read only 64 bytes of data from the module using `Erlang`. Curious, I decided to read from it again, this time using `C`, and the count was equal to `4096`.

I believe that the compiler may be preloading more data into memory, anticipating that I might read more from the file system. As a result, it doesn't need to perform all those operations again when I request additional data, and it can simply return the previously stored data from memory.

am i right or it's completely something else?

Comment: The difference in the count parameter values you observe is a result of the Linux kernel's read-ahead mechanism and not the compiler preloading data.

Comment: @CemPolat The kernel won't use the read-ahead mechanism on a character device.

Comment: Perhaps Erlang is buffering data read from the device like a fully buffered stream opened by C's `fopen()`. You can use the **strace** utility to see the system calls.

Comment: Note: we can read only entire sectors from disks. And for efficiency (and memory management), it is good to read the entire sector in one page of memory. It will be waste of memory and writing to disk, and tracking modification to give you less then one sector.